# Display two images side by side outside of container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty simple layout going on.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img id="imageOne" src="">
            <img id="imageTwo" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the images are added dynamically.  Most of the time, only imageOne is displayed.  This works fine, the image is 100% the width of the 
container.  ImageTwo is only displayed alongside imageOne, never on its own.  To get the images, I have select boxes which when selected, make an Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "./someUrl"
}).done(function(data){

    var url = $('meta[name="base_url"]').attr('content');

    if(data) {
        $.get(url + data)
            .done(function() {
                $('#imageTwo').attr('src', '');
                $('#imageTwo').attr('src', url + data);
                $('#imageTwo').css('display', 'inline');
            }).fail(function() {
                $('#imageTwo').css('display', 'none');
            });
    }
});
```

So that is what the Ajax call for imageTwo looks like (stripped stuff out to make it easier to see).  What I am trying to do is this.  If
imageTwo is added, I do not want it placed below imageOne.  Instead, I need it besides imageOne, and I want them to extend outside of the container,
so a scrollbar will be added to the browser.

I have been trying to display them inline, floating them etc but nothing seems to work.  How can I get them side by side, outside of the container?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/85/)

Thanks

Comment: Make a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for it.

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle which shows 2 images.  What I am trying to do is put them side by side, but not at 50% width, I need them to be full size and would like a scrollbar added.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is maybe the layout that you're after:

https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/86/

Add another div called whatever you like (I called it 'special') and place your images in there. Then add this css.

```
.special {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.special > img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just add the 'special' class to the div via your js when there is two images and I think that should do the job. If not let me know and I'll try and sort something else out.